# How do people find the number of ways you can put together a rubiks cube?

Tags: combinatorics

Just curious. How do people actually find the number of ways you can put together a rubiks cube? How do you find the number of choices? Do you use the same permutation formula?

Insight would be appreciated.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculating the number of permutation is more complex than a classical combinatorial question, since not every permutation of the 6 colors is accessible from the original state.

Rubiks cube is actually a [group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29) with 3 moves (for each dimension) on either the top or bottom layer.

Counting the number of valid states, is actually the size of the group.

More on the group on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube_group)